# How is the polite particle 요 pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

To me it sounds more like 여 (wider mouth) when used at the end of words, while standalone or mid-word 요 is pronounced with a more closed mouth.

#### Example

https://soundcloud.com/talktomeinkorean/ttmik-level-1-lesson-4#t=10:17

The first time the woman speaker pronounces 잠깐만요, the ending sounds more like 여 to me, but when she splits it into silables it's definitely a 요.

Comment: Can you post a link to a pronunciation you have heard, where you have had this confusion?

Comment: Maybe I'm an old fart, but judging from the infuriating number of youngsters misspelling -요 as -여 (e.g., 했어여), I think something is going on with the pronunciation of -요 in the younger generation.

Comment: YouTube: [_The Sound of the Modern Seoul Korean Dialect_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dutvXO3UM7A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I feel like about this is that it is possible, but it would be unintentional.

It's easy to slip tongue and not pronounce 요 clearly enough while speaking fast. Especially, 했어요 sounds very much like 했어여 sometimes. (Yeah, I admit it.. it's me.)

However, ordinary native speakers wouldn't consider themselves pronouncing ~요 like ~여 at the end of sentences.

The youtube linke you provided spells everything with -여, instead of -요, but I find it very strange from a native speaker's perspective. (I live in Seoul) Like I said above, native speakers would still consider themselves that they are pronouncing -요, not -여 at the end of the sentence.

However, I admit that the pronunciation of -요 has become vague compared to that in the past. So, it might be that the dialect is actually in the process of changing. The reason I'm saying this is because I've watched a youtube with Seoul dialect in 1990s, and I felt they articulated each syllables much stronger. (Guess what? I was in Seoul back then as well, and I never thought the pronunciation has changed a bit.)